# I'm getting an odd jQuery ReferenceError in my Ruby on Rails 4.2 Application using gem jquery-rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, passenger, jquery-rails

I recently implemented the following jQuery script in my Ruby on Rails applications. All of them run jquery-rails 4.0.4.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        twitterCheck = setInterval(function() {
          if($('iframe[id^="twitter-widget-"]').length) {
            $('iframe[id^="twitter-widget-"]').each(function () {
              $(this).contents().find(".timeline").attr("style","max-width:100% !important;");
              $(this).attr("style","max-width:100% !important; width: 100% !important;");
            });
        clearInterval(twitterCheck);
          }
        }, 1000);
      });
    </script>
```

I was getting the following error when I look at the page source on the first line $(window):

```
[Error] ReferenceError: Can’t find variable: $
global code (mywebsite.com, line 32)
```

I thought that jquery-rails gem should take care of this. I ended up fixing the error by added the following line.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I decided to check the documentation for jquery-rails [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/jquery-rails/4.0.4). It said that if I wanted to use jQuery2 to change the require statement to jquery2. I did this and I still get the error.

I would like to use the jquery-rails gem since it is updated for the latest versions of jQuery and jQuery2 without having to add the jquery script in `application.html.erb`.

Updated: July 24, 2015 9:30 am CST

Here is my application.js statements for jquery-rails:

```
//= require jquery2
//= require jquery_ujs
```

I tried again and rebooted my server and deployed the application again. I still get the ReferenceError.

Comment: Is this issue with production or development mode?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you followed the instructions from the documentation, requiring the jquery in application.js like this,

```
//= require jquery2
//= require jquery_ujs
```

I would try restarting your server if you haven't done so yet.

UPDATE

For production mode, make sure you precompile  your assets.

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: Updated my answer, let me know if that helps.

Comment: I had done RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile before writing my question. I did your command and got the same error.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that your script is being ran before the rest of your javascript is loaded on the page. Is there a reason why you have your javascript in a script tag and not in your regular assets?

Comment: Honestly I had not thought about it, aaron. I moved it to assets. No error.

Comment: I rarely use JavaScript. When I have I just threw the code in my HTML code. Thanks so much!